# Line breaking in multiple cases mathematical expression

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

How can I align this part of my paper:

```
\subsection{Decision variables}

\noindent$y_{pij}^{mk}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, & \;\;\; \hbox{ If the robot
loads or uloades a part to/from machine $m$ in position $p$ and gripper one
holds a part that should be loaded on machine $i\in \mathcal{M}$ and gripper
two holds a part that should be loaded on machine $j\in \mathcal{M}$}, \\
    0, &\;\;\; \hbox{Otherwise} \end{array} \right.
    $
```

It is published like the following picture.

[image]

As you see, the end of the description of this binary variable is out of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: What about a `\parbox` instead of `\hbox`? Also, you can use the `cases` environment to typeset this kind of thing. Plus, instead of `\noindent`, you should use a display-style math environment.

Comment: Something else you can do is transform the mathematical expression by pure text. For example: “y_pij^mk=1 if the robots loads […] and y_pij^mk=0 otherwise.

Comment: Thank you so much Zoxume. Your answer was perfect. Especially the last part about making the first line of the \parbox at the same height.
It is completely correct now.

Comment: Then don’t forget to upvote it and to click on the tick mark.

Comment: ok but I am completely new here. I signed up few hours ago. How should I do that? :-)

Comment: Read this: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things that you should do:

1. Use a display-style math environment, like `\[ ... \]`.
2. Use the `cases` environment to typeset mathematical cases.
3. Use a `\parbox` to allow your text to be typeset on several lines.

This said, you can do this:

```
\[y_{pij}^{mk} = \begin{cases}
1, & \parbox{5cm}{If the robot loads or uloades a part to/from machine $m$ in position $p$ and gripper one holds a part that should be loaded on machine $i\in \mathcal{M}$ and gripper two holds a part that should be loaded on machine $j\in \mathcal{M}$} \\
0, & \text{Otherwise}
\end{cases}\]
```

The result is:

[image]

You can adjust the width of the `\parbox` to better suit your needs.

To make the first line of the `\parbox` at the same height as the “1”, you can give the `\parbox` command some options:

```
\parbox[t][][t]{length}{Your text}
```

(Found here: *[Tabular, parbox, vertical alignment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10270/tabular-parbox-vertical-alignment)*.)

Result:

[image]

Comment: You may also use `array` construction for this.

Comment: The two cases look a little crowded, so I include `\smallskip` at the end of the `\parbox`.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \left\{%
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \text{\parbox[t][][t]{0.8\textwidth}{If the robot loads or uploads a part to/from machine $m$ in position $p$ and gripper one holds a part that should be loaded on machine $i\in \mathcal{M}$ and gripper two holds a part that should be loaded on machine $j\in \mathcal{M}$}}, \\
            0 & \text{Otherwise}
        \end{array}%
    \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is less code with the cases construction which does the same, plus no need to wrap paroxysmal in the text command

Answer (score 1):

A simple code with `flalign*` and the `dcases*` environment from mathtools:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
  & y_{pij}^{mk}=\begin{dcases*} 1, & \parbox[t]{0.863\linewidth}{ If the robot loads or uloades a part to/from machine $m$ in position $p$ and gripper one holds a part that should be loaded on machine $i ∈ \mathcal{M}$ and gripper two holds a part that should be loaded on machine $j ∈ \mathcal{M}$}, \\ 0, &Otherwise
  \end{dcases*}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]